# List<T> to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, c#

I have the following classes defined

```
public ReportsViewmodel
{
    public GeographicData GeographicData { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class GeographicData
{
    public List<ZipcodeData> Regions { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class  ZipcodeData
{
     //TupleList is defined as public class TupleList<T1, T2> : List<Tuple<T1, T2>>
     public TupleList<double, double> Boundries { get; set; }//Contains list of Lat/Long values for plotting on a map.         
}
```

inside my view, I need to do something like this:

```
foreach (region in GeographicData.Regions)
    foreach (boundry in region.Boundries)
       add item1 & item2 to a 2 dimensional Javascript array
```

In the end, I want my javascript array to look like:

```
var vmBoundries= [[34.1, -85.4], [34.8, -85.234], [34.347, -85.345], [34.541, -85.434], [34.2341, -85.4]];
```

I can't figure out how to access the data from my view. I keep running into scope issue. For example, if I try to use a javascript for loop I can't index into my ViewModel lists because the loop variable is undefined when I call @Model.GeographicData.Regions[i]...

So how do I pull the data from my ViewModel into the Javascript array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd:

1. Transform the data into the format you want
2. Serialize the transformed data into JSON
3. Assign a JavaScript variable to the serialized value.

So, something like this:

```
@{
    IEnumerable<double[]> flattened = vm.GeographicData.Regions
        .SelectMany(region => region.Boundries
            .Select(tpl => new double[] { tpl.Item1, tpl.Item2 }));

    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(flattened);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = @json;
    // do something with arr.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
    var array = (from region in GeographicData.Regions
            select from boundry in region.Boundries
                 select new object[] { boundry.Item1, boundry.Item2 }).ToArray();
```

This will give you a 2D array that you can then just serialize.

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y9KOaq

Answer (score 0):

I would use a javascript serializer to make it easier:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

And add a helper method to `ReportsViewmodel`:

```
public string GetBoundriesJs()
{
    var pairs =
        from r in GeographicData.Regions
        from b in r.Boundries
        select new[] { b.Item1, b.Item2 };

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(pairs);
}
```

Then you can just call it where you need it in your view:

```
var vmBoundries = @Model.GetBoundriesJs();
```